# Deploying an asp.net MVC project to local shared folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I am facing some problems deploying my project . 
In my work , I have been asked to create a site . the previous one is located inside public Drive .`E:\all\**site**\index.html` where everyone could navigate to `https://our.local.application.server.com/site/index.html` to view the site.
What files exactly should i move to the folder ?
 I tried to copy all project folder but what will be my navigation path ? i tried even with `\controllerName`
but i still getting `Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error` in the browser.

(I have to say that there is no problem navigating to *.html files .)

Regards

Adding screenshots

[image: This is the project folder]

[image: This is the error thrown]

Comment: You will need to figure out what the underlying error is.

Comment: Hi @mason , is this the right way to do it ? because when i copied all project folder , how the web browser will know to navigate to the routeConfiguration ..

Comment: Web browsers don't need to know about route configuration. That's the server's responsibility. What you need to do is figure out what the underlying error is.

Comment: @mason what do you mean underlying error ? i only see is = Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error.Is it enough to just copy the folder?

Comment: That page is yellow, right? That's called the "Yellow Screen of Death". And it will include instructions on how you can see the actual error.

Comment: @mason no, the page is not yellow white background with no instructions..

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the error page?

Comment: @Locke125  I did.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that an error is occuring, but there is another error happening in what your application does to handle that error. You might look at the event viewer to see what the first one is. I've had this error sometimes when something is not set correctly on the web server, web.config, or error handling setup to name a few reasons.

Comment: Wait, you just copied your project files? No - you need to [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) to IIS or another web server. You shouldn't see both web.debug.config and web.release.config or the controllers folder.

Comment: @SteveGreene i did publish also ... in the publish method i chose "file system" but then what? tried the folder path but its not working. by the way, i do not have access to the IIS manager, only to the current folder in order to upload there.
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to take the published contents and copy them to the proper IIS folder. This assumes somebody setup the app pool and did the other configuration steps outlined in my link.

Comment: "Another exception occurred while executing custom page" - you have unhandled exception which prevents custom error message to be shown. Try remove `customError` redirect parts in web.config (return to default standard YSOD state) & see which error appears. Make sure all references are exist in `bin` folder too.